# Field Display Question

Tags: ms-access

I am working on a personnel accountability system, and I have a question about getting a field to display a value based on a value in another table that is a sub-report of the same form.

For instance, I have a tabbed interface, and the first tab is a snapshot of the person, vital data and such. I have a tab that lists retention information. The tab has a sub-report that links to another table that stores all of the flags (adverse actions) for employees. These two tables are linked together with a relationship, linking each flag to an individual employee.

I would like to have a field on the first tab titled `FlagSnapshot`display either a value of `Flagged` or `Not Flagged` based on the value of the field `FlagStatus` from the other table. The field `FlagStatus` form the other table has possible values of `Active`, `Removed`, and `Permanent`. So again, if value in field `FlagStatus` in table `Flags` equals `Active`, I would like the `FlagSnapshot`field in table `Personnel` to display `Flagged`. I also need to set conditions so that if the field `FlagStatus` in table `Flags`has the value of `Removed`, then I need the field `FlagSnapshot`to display the value of `Not Flagged`. There are a few other values too in field `FlagStatus`, but only two values in the field `FlagSnapshot`.

Also, it is possible for one employee to have multiple flags, and I need to make sure that all of them are taken into account. If the table `Flags` has two or three flags for the same employee and one of them reads `Removed` and the other reads `Active`, I need the flag snapshot field to display a value of `Flagged`.

I apologize in advance for the long explanation. Also, this is not homework, it's a project I am working on at work to make things more easily tracked.

Comment: Do you have to store the value in the FlagSnapshot field? Seems redundant since you can just display the value on the form when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a mix of VBA and SQL, assuming you have normalized data structure (at least partially). For example, I would expect to have table **FlagStatus** to be a separate table and linked to other tables.

**Step 1**: Add Column **Priority** to the FlagStatus table that lists ALL FlagStatuses:
[image]

**Step 2**: Create a query (*GetFlagStatusQuery*) that returns FlagStatus with highest priority for a particular Employee:
[image]

**Step 3**: Create a function that returns the desired FlagStatus representation. Something like this:

```
Function GetFlagStatus(employeeId As Long) As String

Dim rs As Recordset
Dim qdf As QueryDef

FlagStatus = ""

Set qdf = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("GetFlagStatusQuery")
qdf.Parameters("EmployeeId_parameter") = employeeId

Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset()

If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
    Select Case rs("FlagStatus")
    Case "Active"
        FlagStatus = "Flagged"
    Case "Removed"
        FlagStatus = "Not Flagged"
    End Select
End If

End Function
```

**Step 4**: Use the GetFlagStatus function in your form/tab and pass EmployeeId parameter from the Form. For example, for a textbox control the source would be: *=GetFlagStatus([EmployeeId])*